# Need help to extract following data

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Input Text :

```
05/08/04 OUTPT LABORATORY 35.00 35.00 35.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
80053
05/10/04 OFFICE MEDICAL 14.00 9.50 0.00 0.00 9.50 0.00 1
84436
05/10/04- HOME MED EQUIP 32.00 32.00 32.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
05/13/04 A4595RR
05/10/04- HOME MED EQUIP 10.00 3.75 0.00 0.00 3.75 0.00 1
05/13/04 L3800RR
05/14/04 PHYSIOTHERAPY 23.00 23.00 7.00 0.00 16.00 0.00
97110
05/14/04 PHYSIOTHERAPY 14.00 9.00 0.00 0.00 9.00 0.00 1
97140
```

Expected output in excel as below format :

| Service Date | Type of Service | Procedure Number | Amount Billed | Amount Allowed | Amount We Paid | Non Covered | Deductible | Copayment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/08/04 | OUTPT LABORATORY | 80053 | 35 | 35 | 35 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/10/04 | OFFICE MEDICAL | 84436 | 14 | 9.5 | 0 | 0 | 9.5 | 0 |
| 05/10/04- 05/13/04 | HOME MED EQUIP | A4595RR | 32 | 32 | 32 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/10/04- 05/13/04 | HOME MED EQUIP | L3800RR | 10 | 3.75 | 0 | 0 | 3.75 | 0 |
| 05/14/04 | PHYSIOTHERAPY | 97110 | 23 | 23 | 7 | 0 | 16 | 0 |
| 05/14/04 | PHYSIOTHERAPY | 97140 | 14 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |

Question: I was able to extract but the problem is in cases like these data format is not in exact order `"05/10/04- HOME MED EQUIP 32.00 32.00 32.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 05/13/04 A4595RR"`  There might be two dates in some cases only one date format ? Can someone help me on this ?

#Python

I have text file as input and once i read file i have to identify above piece of input that i was able to achieve but now i have data that is not consistent but need to read above input and load excel file similar to below output

Note: there is date that is dynamic and sometimes its not available.

Tried this but can able to read only first two lines that too with missing of infomation

```
import pandas as pd
import re

input_file_path = r'C:\Users\test\Downloads\PracticalAssessmentFiles\Input.txt'

output_file_path = r'C:\Users\test\Downloads\PracticalAssessmentFiles\output.xlsx'

with open(input_file_path, 'r') as file:
    input_string = file.read()

pattern = r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2,4}(?:\s*-\s*\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2,4})?)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+([\dA-Z]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)'
matches = re.findall(pattern, input_string)

data = []
for match in matches:
    service_date, service_type, procedure_number, billed, allowed, paid, non_covered, deductible, copayment = match
    data.append({
        "Service Date": service_date,
        "Type of Service": service_type,
        "Procedure Number": procedure_number,
        "Amount Billed": billed,
        "Amount Allowed": allowed,
        "Amount We Paid": paid,
        "Non Covered": non_covered,
        "Deductible": deductible,
        "Copayment": copayment
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False)

print(f"Data has been processed and saved to {output_file_path}")
```

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your title to something that summarizes the actual problem you're facing [ask]. Also [formatting](/help/formatting) makes your question more readable

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask.  Perhaps this can be a good basis for you to expand on.

```
import re

oddlines = re.compile(r"([0-9/-]*) ([A-Z ]*) ([0-9. ]*)")

for num,line in enumerate(open('x.txt')):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        parts = oddlines.match(line)
        dt, title, nums = parts.groups()
        nums = nums.split()
    else:
        if dt[-1] == '-':
            dt1,proc = line.split()
            dt += dt1
        else:
            proc = line.strip()
        row = [dt, title, proc] + nums[:5]
        print(','.join(row))
```

Output:

```
05/08/04,OUTPT LABORATORY,80053,35.00,35.00,35.00,0.00,0.00
05/10/04,OFFICE MEDICAL,84436,14.00,9.50,0.00,0.00,9.50
05/10/04-05/13/04,HOME MED EQUIP,A4595RR,32.00,32.00,32.00,0.00,0.00
05/10/04-05/13/04,HOME MED EQUIP,L3800RR,10.00,3.75,0.00,0.00,3.75
05/14/04,PHYSIOTHERAPY,97110,23.00,23.00,7.00,0.00,16.00
05/14/04,PHYSIOTHERAPY,97140,14.00,9.00,0.00,0.00,9.00
```